# Thread doesn't start inside onClickListener()

Tags: android, sockets, view

I have a button and I had set an `onClickListener()` as follows

```
playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Socket s;
                    PrintWriter writer;
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < openClientSockets.size() ; i += 1) {
                        s = openClientSockets.get(i);
                        try {
                            writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                            writer.print("play");
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

I have set a debugger on the `onClick`. It is fired but the Thread doesn't starts.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: mmm so you're meaning that if you set a breakpoint inside the thread it doesn't stop... What about the log? Are some exception thrown?

Comment: put debug point in run method.

Comment: no exceptions are being thrown (referring to logcat)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger just stops the thread the breakpoint is set.
So if you want to see if the second thread is working, your need to set the breakpoint in the `run()` method.

Comment: I have put 2 breakpoints, one inside the onclick, and second inside the run method.  The debugger does not stops inside the run method

Comment: you could also try replacing `yourThread.start()` with `yourThread.run()`

Comment: this will not start a new thread. Instead this will simply call the `run()`  method of the thread.

Comment: oh you're right. that was stupid of me... :D
can you tell me where you exactly set your breakpoints?